# Make Bootstrap-Select button go full width (responsive) with btn-block

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

I'm experimenting with the [Bootstrap Select Field from silvio moreto](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/) and it turns out that it's using bootstrap `btn` and `form-control` classes.

My select field is surrounded by a responsive column `col-md-1`.
But if the content becomes someting really large ... the select fields **width exceeds** the width of its surrounding column `col-md-1`,

I found `btn-block` to use the entire width of the parent element,
but how to integrate with the Rails Form Builder?

```
%div.col-md-1
  = fields_for :user do |f|
    = f.select :interest, options_for_select([
      ["one",{"data-value" => "one", 
              "data-content" => "<i class='fa fa-gift'></i> One"}], 
      ["two",{"data-value" => "two", 
              "data-content" => "<i class='fa fa-question-circle-o'></i> Two"}], 
      ["three",{"data-value" => "three", 
              "data-content" => "<i class='fa fa-soccer-ball-o'></i> Three"}]
      ]), {}, :multiple => "multiple", 
              :title => "Choose what you like", 
              :class => "btn-block selectpicker"
```

results in

```
<select multiple="multiple" title="Choose what you like" 
  class="btn-block selectpicker" 
  name="user[interest][]" 
  id="user_interest" 
  style="display: none;">

  <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select show-tick btn-block">
    <button type="button" 
      class="btn dropdown-toggle form-control selectpicker btn-default" 
      data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="searchprofile_interest" 
      title="One, Two, Three">
      <span class="filter-option pull-left">
      <i class="fa fa-gift"></i> One, 
      <i class="fa fa-question-circle-o"></i> Two, 
      <i class="fa fa-soccer-ball-o"></i> Three</span>&nbsp;
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
  </div>

</select>
```

Is there any way to bring `btn-block` into the button?

```
<button type="button" 
      class="btn dropdown-toggle form-control selectpicker btn-default"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to attach btn-block to `data-style`, as shown [here](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#button-classes). So, your code would be like:

```
%div.col-md-1
  = fields_for :user do |f|
    = f.select :interest, options_for_select([
      ["one",{"data-value" => "one", 
          "data-content" => "<i class='fa fa-gift'></i> One"}], 
      ["two",{"data-value" => "two", 
          "data-content" => "<i class='fa fa-question-circle-o'></i> Two"}], 
      ["three",{"data-value" => "three", 
          "data-content" => "<i class='fa fa-soccer-ball-o'></i> Three"}]
      ]), {}, :multiple => "multiple", 
              :title => "Choose what you like", 
              :class => "selectpicker"
              :"data-style" => "btn-block"
```

Comment: doesnt work for me, tried also as html options with `{ "data-class" => "btn block" }`

Comment: @StefHej I'm sorry, I don't know where I got `data-class` from; the documentation clearly says `data-style` and somewhere along the way "class" came to mind.